# Loading a webpage in webview which is in indain local language (kannada)

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a web page in webview which is in local lang (kannada) , but instead of kannada lang or letters  i am getting squares , how to load web page of different lang in webview .

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do that you have to generate webfont for **kannada** font.

To generate web font look at this url:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `UTF-8` encoding in your webView like:

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
mWebView.loadData(topHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```

change the previous code to match with your code.

hope this works for you, please give me a feedback.